Do the controlling voltages or currents act independent of the existence of a dependent source?
Dependent sources confuse me. We were taught a method using input and output resistances to find out whether a dependent source is VVVS, VVCS, CCVS, CCCS. Apparently for a voltage controlled source if the input resistance of the dependent source is low, it 'loads' the circuit and ends up decreasing the voltage across the voltage controller branch thereby altering it. That's why the input voltage must be high.
And for low input resistance in case of current controlled source, we need the source (source + controlling variable) to be able to attain a current through its controller branch and therefore cannot have high resistance. While finding input resistance, which terminals should we consider? The dependent source's or the controlling branch's?
Do I have a conceptual lapse in understanding what is input and output resistance?

Now in this question, if there was no dependent source, ix would have been Vs/(10+15) which is not the case with the existence of dependent source.

Here the controller branch is actually Vin and the resistor connected to it and Vo is the dependent voltage right? So while testing for input voltage, we must remove the controller branch and apply it across those terminals? And for output resistance we must apply a test voltage across the terminals of the dependent source?
In this question, the justification for it being a CCVS in the case that g tends to infinity was given by connecting a test voltage across the input terminals once and then the output terminals. In both cases the test current was infinite because g was infinite and therefore it was concluded that Rin and Rout were close to 0 and it is a CCVS. I don't understand how. Also does the controller branch value depend on the existence of the dependent source?

Please provide citations for these images and cite the source. Also please provide an attempt at a solution of what you think it should be.
